# Insert line break in \cventry

Tags: line-breaking, moderncv

What do I have to change in the following code to drop my company name, and company location to the line below my job title?  I tried them around within the separate brackets but my LaTeX knowledge is quite limited.

I tried breaking it down to the following lines.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyhead}[1]{}
\maketitle
\vspace{-10mm}
\section{Engineering Experience}
\cventry{Sept 2008--Present}{Mechanical Engineer}{\href {http://www.bmpc.com/}{Bechtel Marine Propulsion Corporation}}{West Mifflin, PA}{}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Managed projects to ensure appropriate
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Selecting text and clicking the button marked `{}` will highlight that text as code, as you see in my edit.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: That code doesn't compile at all here.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make your code compilable you have to specify, at least, a theme, e.g.

```
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}
```

and a name for the CV, e.g.

```
\firstname{John}\familyname{Doe}
```

Then, all you have to do to achieve what you want is to insert a `\newline` at the beginning of the third mandatory argument of `\cventry` (it works whatever theme you choose).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep}

\firstname{John}\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyhead}[1]{}
\maketitle
\vspace{-10mm}
\section{Engineering Experience}
\cventry{Sept 2008--Present}{Mechanical Engineer}{\newline\href {http://www.bmpc.com/}{Bechtel Marine Propulsion Corporation}}{West Mifflin, PA}{}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item Managed projects to ensure appropriate
\end{itemize}%
}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]